# Trigger PHP on simple Jquery event with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Based the ID of div clicked I want to be able to change an embed link.

This code previously worked when I set up the page with a form.

```
<embed src=
  "/<?php
     if (isset($_POST['playlist'])) { // if ANY of the divs were clicked
         echo $_POST['playlist']; // echo the choice
     }else{
         echo "5125962"; // As a default playlist
     }
?>">
```

However my client disliked the page refreshing. Building on that, I discard the forms for this JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".playlist").click(function(){
      var playlist = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/update/apps/music.php',
        data : playlist,
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
          $(".PlaylistHolder").load('/update/apps/music.php');
        }
      });
    }); 
});
```

in place of the .ajax function I also tried

```
$(".PlaylistHolder").load('/update/apps/music.php', playlist);
```

The idea was that in place of the whole page refreshing, it would reload the contents of the "PlayListHolder" div. I'm not getting any syntax errors, but my variable won't carry across. In my PHP I tried $_GET and $_REQUEST as well. Any ideas?

Normally I fix my code on my own, but given the nature of debugging I think I'm going to throw up if I the default song one more time. Thanks guys

Comment: Close tags are there for the click function. Just copied wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posting data should be formatted as a JSON object.You need to format data to post like this,

```
var list = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/update/apps/music.php',
          data :{playlist: list},
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
          $(".PlaylistHolder").load('/update/apps/music.php');
        }
      });
```

Or else you can post a serialized form like this

```
data :$('#yourFormId').Serialize(),
```

See Example [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Comment: You were right about formatting as JSON. Worked perfectly with the .load function. I think with the .ajax I was sending the information but then losing it when I loaded it back into the page.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually passing the returned AJAX data. The parameter passed to your function contains whatever your ajax call got from the file. Change

```
$(".PlaylistHolder").load('/update/apps/music.php');
```

to

```
$(".PlaylistHolder").load(data);
```